# List manipulation and conversion in Java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I have an input list like:
`var list = Arrays.asList("etc->hosts", "etc->dockers->ssl->certs", "root");`

And I am trying to convert it into nested map:
`{etc={dockers={ssl={certs={}}}, hosts={}}, root={}}`

I tried to split the key from input list with dot i.e. '->' and tried to iterate over to construct a map: Map<String, Map>.
Tried`.groupingBy()` `.computeIfAbsent()` `.stream().map().filter().collect()`, both of them failed.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code, and explain exactly what problem you are having with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need streams, just a simple `for` loop that walks down each chain:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String chain : list) {
    Map<String, Object> current = map;
    for (String node : chain.split("->")) {
        current = (Map<String, Object>)current.computeIfAbsent(node, n -> new HashMap<>());
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the unchecked cast warnings, you can define a self-referential map like this (assuming you don't plan to mix in additional value types):

```
class NestingMap extends HashMap<String, NestingMap> {}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/tXRG1k)